Unexpected output when displaying file content after using mmap()
I am parsing a .elf file to edit a few details in it. I am opening the file using open() and then creating a memory map for it using mmap() for easier editing.
The problem is that I am getting unexpected behaviour after I create the memory map.
In order to debug the issue and see if I am using the open() and mmap() functions correctly, I trimmed down the code to simply print the content of the .elf file. However, even when I did that, the printed content was not the same output as I get when I do a objdump -s myfile.elf
Please bare in mind, that this is not my full code, this is just a trimmed down version for the purpose of the question and it is still not working.
All what I am looking for now is to print the file content and have a same output as that of the objdump command
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include   <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct iFi  {
  unsigned char               *pB;       // memory mapped file
  void           *hFmap;
  void           *hFile;
  int             handle_File;
  unsigned long            fSize;       // file size
  struct stat       sts;       /* File status */
  char        szFN[1024];       // file name
} XFILE;

int main (int argc, char **argv)  {
    if(argc != 2)    
        return 1;
    
    XFILE myfile;
    XFILE *pF = &myfile;
    memset (&pF->pB, 0, sizeof (pF->pB));
    memset (&pF->hFmap, 0, sizeof (pF->hFmap));
    memset (&pF->hFile, 0, sizeof (pF->hFile));
    memset (&pF->szFN, 0, sizeof (pF->szFN));

    strcpy (pF->szFN, argv[1]);
    mode_t perms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    pF->handle_File = open(pF->szFN, O_RDWR, perms);
    if (pF->handle_File < 0)  {
        perror("open");
        return (1);
    }

    int n = stat (pF->szFN, &pF->sts);
    if (n != 0) return(1000);                     // failed
    pF->fSize = pF->sts.st_size;
    //pF->hFmap = CreateFileMapping (pF->hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE /*PAGE_WRITECOPY*/, 0, 0, NULL);
    pF->pB = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mmap(NULL, pF->fSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, pF->handle_File, 0));
    if (pF->pB == NULL) return 1000;             // can't map view of file
    printf("Contents of file = 0x%x\n", *pF->pB);

    return 0;

}

Here is my expected output (first 0xFF bytes)
0000 00000320 9d050000 c9050000 cd050000  ... ............
0010 c5050000 c5050000 c5050000 00000000  ................

and here is the actual output I get
Contents of file = 0x7f

As you can see, there is no 0x7f anywhere in my file and even if I print the whole content of pF->pB I get:
0x0000000100288000 "\U0000007fELF\U00000001\U00000001\U00000001"


OT: memset (&pF->pB, 0, sizeof (pF->pB)); is exactly the same as  myfile.pB = NULL;. Why all those memset calls? What is the need for pF? Also, fSize should be a size_t. And don't use all those weird abbreviations, give your variables proper, readable (and therefore understandable and maintainable) names. Your style also isn't consistent, making the code less readable, understandable and maintainable.

Oh, and static_cast<...>(...) is a C++ expression, not C. Are you really programming in C or C++? If you're programming in C++ there are better ways to write that code. And if you're programming in C then you can't use static_cast.

And on platforms where you have mmap (POSIX systems like Linux or macOS), the return value of main is limited to 8 bits (i.e. -128 to 127). Your return of 1000 will be truncated.

You are obviously opening an ELF file and reading the first byte(s). An elf file starts with \x7fELF, so everything works as expected. objdump -s displays the contents of the ELF sections, so the header is not printed here. That's why you cannot observe the ELF magic.

As shown at Wikipedia the first byte of an elf file is 0x7F. If you wasnt to modify the content of the file then you first need to understand the complete file structure.

You could use xxd -l 32 file to compare the actual file contents to the output of your program

@Someprogrammerdude as I said, the code is trimmed down just for the sake of the question, generally I have more meaningful names for my variables.

Do you have any idea how can I print the sections of my elf file so that I can have a similar output to the objdump -s ?

Begin by including <elf.h> and use the structures it defines.

@OmarKhouly The easiest is probably to use one of the available ELF libraries.

@Someprogrammerdude ... the return value of main is limited to 8 bits ... The full value is available: "The exit value in si_status shall be equal to the full exit value (that is, the value passed to _exit(), _Exit(), or exit(), or returned from main()); it shall not be limited to the least significant eight bits of the value."  Of course, Linux is broken/buggy.


However, even when I did that, the printed content was not the same output as I get when I do a objdump -s myfile.elf

The printed content should match what you see when you do
$ hd myfile.elf

Memory mapping the file contents is not the same as the process done on loadint an .elf binary, as this requires dlopen(3) library call.
Objdump reads and prints .elf specific info, like section contents and requires format to be ELF, while mmap(2) just maps the file contents (of any kind of file) in memory, so you can see the file contents as if it was memory.
This means that, if you map with mmap(2), then you need to interpret the ELF header and search for the sections by mapping the addresses yourself.
